# How can a print elements in a list randomly in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I've got a list which I want to print in random order. Here is the code I've written so far:

```
import random
words=["python","java","constant","immutable"]
for i in words:
    print(i, end=" ")
input("") #stops window closing
```

I've tried a variety of things to print them out randomly, such as making a variable which selects only one of them randomly and then deleting the randomly. I would then repeat this step until they are all deleted and within another variable. Then I would put the variables in a list then print them out. This kept on generating errors though. Is there another way this can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`random.shuffle()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) to shuffle a list, in-place:

```
import random

words = ["python", "java", "constant", "immutable"]
random.shuffle(words)
print(*words)

input('')
```

Demo:

```
>>> import random
>>> words = ["python", "java", "constant", "immutable"]
>>> random.shuffle(words)
>>> words
['python', 'java', 'constant', 'immutable']
```

If you wanted to preserve `words` (maintain the order), you can use `sorted()` with a random key to return a new randomized list:

```
words = ["python", "java", "constant", "immutable"]
print(*sorted(words, key=lambda k: random.random()))
```

This leaves `words` unaltered:

```
>>> words = ["python", "java", "constant", "immutable"]
>>> sorted(words, key=lambda k: random.random())
['immutable', 'java', 'constant', 'python']
>>> words
['python', 'java', 'constant', 'immutable']
```

Comment: Nice, I like that technique of providing random.random() as key.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import random
words2 = words[::]
random.shuffle(words2)
for w in words2:
    print(w, end=" ")
```

Notice that I copied the original list first, in case you want to preserve it. If you don't mind shuffling it, this should do the trick:

```
import random
random.shuffle(words)
for w in words:
    print(w, end=" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
random.choice([1,2,3])
#random element from the iterable
```

hope it helps, random.choice() returns randomly chosen element from the list.

Comment: I think the op wants a list of elements which are randomly arranged, instead of getting a random element from list.

Comment: I don't know he says he want to print them in random order, doesn't he?

Comment: yeah, like `['a','b','c']` gives `['b', 'a', 'c']`, not a single character say `b`. But your code will only retrieve a single element, I suppose?

Answer (score -1):

If you really want to, you could use `random.randint` to pick a random integer, then print the word that corresponds with that integer.